# Finding the largest line segment

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, spheres

Take two spheres each of radius $a$.

Their centers are separated by distance $d_0$.

[image]

How shall we find the largest line segment among all lines joining a point on sphere $A$ to a point on sphere $B$?

> **My try**

Just by looking at the diagram, I can guess that the largest line segment will be $d_0+2a$. However I cannot find a proof even though it may be simple.

Comment: First idea: Due to symmetry, the line has to pass through the centre point between the two spheres. Now, you can consider the angle that the line makes with the line that connects the two center points ...

Answer (score 2):

For a point $P$ on circle centre $A$ and a point $Q$ on circle centre $B$, the triangle inequality gives us $$|PQ|\le |PA|+|AB|+|BQ|=d_o+2a.$$

This is therefore the maximum that can be attained.